# What is the graphics card driver for AMD Radeon 8490?

Tags: drivers, fglrx, amd-graphics, ros

I have installed ROS in Ubuntu 14.04 and in order to use scan data from laser scan I have to install the ATI graphics driver.
I searched the AMD website and did not get one for my AMD Radeon 8490.
So I tried to run:
sudo apt-get install fglrx
But it does not seem to work cuz after installaion done, my machine just cannot boot appropriately showing everything is of low level.

Can someone tell me what is the graphic driver fro AMD Radeon 8490?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: OpenGL support on many AMD cards is pretty good out of the box in 16.04 using the open source driver. If that's not an option, try http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/linux.

Comment: I believe there is not one suitable for amd 8490...

Comment: Section "Radeon™ HD 8000 – HD 8400, HD 7000 – HD 7600, HD 6000, and HD 5000 Series" lists a driver for Ubuntu 14.04.2. The 8400 series "should" include 8490. Again, for any card more than a year old, the open source driver should be the go to; it supports OpenGL 4 features, if that's what you need. I think Vulkan and OpenCL are proprietary only features for AMD - at least for now. Intel has an open source OpenCL project and it would be great if AMD followed suit.